# Probability measure in a finite set and its domain and codomain

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider a family $J=((X^i)_i,\nu)$, of finite sets $X^i$ and by a probability measure $\nu$ over $X=\times (X^i)_{i\in I}$.

What is the domain and the codomain of $\nu$ and what does it mean that the probability measure is defined over $X$ (does it mean on $X$ or this means something else)? I thought that $\nu$ is a function s.t. $\nu: X\to [0,1]$, since $\nu$ denotes the probability distribution, or am I missing something?

Comment: You can think of each $X^i$ as a _finite measurable_ space where the sigma field of $X^i$ is just its power set, call it $\mathscr{F}_i.$ Given the $\mathscr{F}_i,$ then $\nu$ is (most likely) defined on the _product_ sigma field of the $\mathscr{F}_i.$ And by the product sigma algebra, I mean the minimal sigma field containing $\prod X^{i_\alpha} \times \prod \{x_{i_\beta}\}$ where the $i_\alpha$ and $i_\beta$ are the indices $i$ (no repetitions), $\beta$ runs over a finite set and each $x_{i_\beta} \in X^{i_\beta}$ (in other words, we fix finitely many coordinates and the rest is everything)

Comment: @Will M. explain me something, is the minimal sigma field defined as $\Pi X^i\times\Pi \{x^j\}$, where $\{x^j\}\in (X^j)_{j\neq i}$ is a singleton, in every case? 

Note here that, I changed the notation with $i_{\alpha}$ and $i_{\beta}$ in $i$ and $j$ respectively, for simplicity.

Comment: Formally, you define $X = \prod X^i$ and then $p_j:X \to X^j$ by $(x^i) \to x^j$ (the projection onto $j$th coordinate). Then, the product sigma field is the minimal sigma field making all $p_j$ _measurable_, in other words, the minimal sigma field for which each set $p_j^{-1}(E_j)$ is measurable, where $E_j$ is runs through _all measurable subset_ of $X^j.$ Now, in your case, $E_j$ is by definition any subset of $X^j$ and $X^j$ is finite, so we can take $E_j$ a subset with one element (a "singleton"). Notice that one can "identify" $p_j^{-1}(x^j) = \prod_{i \neq j} X^i \times \{x^j\}.$